# TypeScript reports no exported member when re-exporting library

Tags: typescript, monkeypatching

We're trying to work around an open issue in an open source library (let's call it openfoo) without having to fork it.

In *our* private library, we have a dependency on openfoo and a devDependency on @types/openfoo. Our library contains the file openfoo-patch.ts, which looks like this:

```
import * as openfoo from 'openfoo';
openfoo.Bar.prototype.etc = function () {}; // monkey patch
export * from 'openfoo';
```

In our other library modules (call one xyz) we do:

```
import { Bar } from '../openfoo-patch';
```

This guarantees that our patch runs before any other modules execute.

*(Note that the second project is also a library, so there's no obvious way to say "run this at startup.")*

Everything works fine, including unit/integration tests.

However, when we tried to build **another** library that has a dependency on our private library above, we get

> node_modules/@ourcompany/ourfirstlibrary/build/xyz.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module
>   '"../.../oursecondlibrary/node_modules/@ourcompany/ourfirstlibrary/build/openfoo-patch"'
>   has no exported member 'Bar'.
>
> 1 import { Bar } from '../openfoo-patch';

We've tried moving @types/openfoo to a full dependency in the first library; that makes no difference. Installing @types/openfoo in the second library did not help either.

How can we get our second library to compile?

(Currently our first library uses TypeScript v3.6.4 and our second uses v3.8.2.)

---

## Update

One workaround appears to be to remove the
`export * from 'openfoo';`
from the patch file, then change the other modules to

```
import '../openfoo-patch'; // ALWAYS import before openfoo
import { Bar } from 'openfoo';
```

This does require two imports, and it requires callers to remember to do this.

Comment: Hi @TrueWill, I am having a similar problem. I don't want to use your workaround because won't that break tree-shaking? Did you ever find a better solution?

Comment: @mariaines Not that I recall; this was at a previous employer.